# What is the rank of the differentiation operator on Pn? What is the kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, education

For this question I was thinking of saying $P_n(x)=Ax^n+Ax^{n-1}+...+Ax^2+Ax^1+1$ and finding the first derivative $P'n(x)=n.Ax^{n-1}+(n-1)Ax^{n-2}+...+2Ax^1+A+0$ so in matrix form would get a $n$ by $1$ matrix with $n-1$ rows being non-zero and $1$ row being zero. So the rank is $n-1$ and form the rank-nullity theorem $Rank(A)+N(A)=n$ where $N(A)=dim (Ker(Pn))=1$. I am unsure if this is correct as well if the differentiation operator just means to differentiation one time or to differentiation up to n times. Also unsure if the constants A should have some index to differentiation them and if its $ker(P_n)$ and not $Ker(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\dim P_n=n+1$ and clearly $\dim\ker(A)=1$ hence $\dim\operatorname{im}(A)=n$

Comment: Why is Pn=n+1 and not n, the index is n so I assume the dim Pn=n, like how for R^2 the index is 2 and Din R^2=2

Comment: Consider the usual basis $\{x^0,x^1,\dots,x^n\}$ has $n+1$ elements

Comment: ok so what about the differniation operator does it imply to differentiation one?

Comment: Well notice $A$ only maps scalar multiples of $x^0$ to $0$, so $x^0$ spans our kernel and thus the dimension of our kernel is $1$.

Comment: ok so it should be and N by 1 matrix then

Comment: $A$ can be represented by an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix with rank $n$ and nullity $1$... not sure what you're trying to say

Comment: I was think of just writing the matrix of the differential of Pn, so P'n matrix would be (n.An (n-1)An-1..... 2A2 A1 0), so its and 1 by n+1 matrix. how would it be n+1 row?

Comment: I do not think you understand how a matrix encodes a linear transformation. Try multiplying what you have with a column coordinate vector corresponding to a polynomial.

Comment: I learnt in class matrix representation of linear transformation, I read online that differential operators a linear transformations so I have [P'n]= 1 x n+1 matrix, but I think you are saying if I multiply the constant by the variables I wont get the correct as, but for it to be a (n+1)x(n+1) that would mean I would have to differniate the polynomial n times and writing the matrix form for those linear expressions

Comment: I get what are saying, just one more question is the rank of Pn which is equal n the same as the rank of the differentiation operaroe on Pn